# xwiki (docker) installation on synology with 500 – Internal Server Error

Tags: docker, mariadb, synology, xwiki

I'm trying to launch a **xwiki-installation** on my synology nas. First I got the mariadb-packet and run it successfully. I connected to the with myphpadmin and create a xwiki user and database.

After than I got the docker-packet, inside I got the xwiki:latest and run it under the same network.

I set the following vars:

```
XWIKI:mysql_tomcat
DB_PORT:3307
DB_DATABASE:xwiki
DB_PASSWORD:....
DB_USER:xwiki
DB_HOST:localhost
```

And start ...

But when I try to connect to Port 8080, I got a **HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error** with a long trace

Anyone has an idea, what I do wrong?

I tried to put the real IP instead of localhost and i tried to set the port with : aft the IP ... but with no luck :(

First trace (can't post the whole ...):

```
HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error

Type Exception Report

Message com.xpn.xwiki.XWikiException: Error number 11007 in 0: Failed to extract Entity Resource Reference from URL [http://192.168.0.100:8080/bin/view/Main/]

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: com.xpn.xwiki.XWikiException: Error number 11007 in 0: Failed to extract Entity Resource Reference from URL [http://192.168.0.100:8080/bin/view/Main/]  org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processException(RequestProcessor.java:520)   org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:427)   org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:228)    org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1913)     org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:449)    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)    com.xpn.xwiki.web.ActionFilter.doFilter(ActionFilter.java:112)  org.xwiki.wysiwyg.filter.ConversionFilter.doFilter(ConversionFilter.java:109)   org.xwiki.container.servlet.filters.internal.SetHTTPHeaderFilter.doFilter(SetHTTPHeaderFilter.java:63)  org.xwiki.container.servlet.filters.internal.SavedRequestRestorerFilter.doFilter(SavedRequestRestorerFilter.java:208)   org.xwiki.container.servlet.filters.internal.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:111)   org.xwiki.resource.servlet.RoutingFilter.doFilter(RoutingFilter.java:132)

Root Cause

com.xpn.xwiki.XWikiException: Error number 11007 in 0: Failed to extract Entity Resource Reference from URL [http://192.168.0.100:8080/bin/view/Main/]  com.xpn.xwiki.XWiki.initializeResourceFromURL(XWiki.java:1030)  com.xpn.xwiki.XWiki.getXWiki(XWiki.java:890)    com.xpn.xwiki.web.XWikiAction.execute(XWikiAction.java:282)     com.xpn.xwiki.web.XWikiAction.execute(XWikiAction.java:215)     org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:425)   org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:228)    org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1913)     org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:449)    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)    com.xpn.xwiki.web.ActionFilter.doFilter(ActionFilter.java:112)  org.xwiki.wysiwyg.filter.ConversionFilter.doFilter(ConversionFilter.java:109)   org.xwiki.container.servlet.filters.internal.SetHTTPHeaderFilter.doFilter(SetHTTPHeaderFilter.java:63)  org.xwiki.container.servlet.filters.internal.SavedRequestRestorerFilter.doFilter(SavedRequestRestorerFilter.java:208)   org.xwiki.container.servlet.filters.internal.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:111)   org.xwiki.resource.servlet.RoutingFilter.doFilter(RoutingFilter.java:132)
```

Comment: I think you should ask your question on https://devops.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks I'll try my luck there
https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/8873/xwiki-docker-installation-on-synology-with-500-internal-server-error